# How to add Ruby into this HTML tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

First, the answer to this is probably quite obvious, but I couldn't figure out how to search for this problem...

I want to embed Google Maps into by Ruby on Rails website using this code:

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=[MY API KEY HERE]&q=#{User.first.address}"
    allowfullscreen>
```

I want to insert the address using a Ruby method (User.first.address) as you can see there. However, I can't quite figure out how to embed Ruby here?

I know that you can usually do `<%= some ruby code %>` but I can't put it in that form in the middle of my HTML here... How do I make sure that the `#{}` part get recognized as Ruby? Is that at all possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your html file in .erb or in .html? maybe it is .html that's why it's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if your file is some_file.html.erb
then you can use 
    <%=User.first.address%>
You can not use #{User.first.address} to insert something into html code

Comment: Wow, how stupid of me. Indeed, I put it in a wrong file. It's now in a html.erb file and using <%=..%> works perfectly within the tag. Thanks!